# How to do a cartesian product of a variable number of lists in Julia?

Tags: arrays, julia, cartesian-product

For each value j in the set {1, 2, ..., n} where the value of n can vary (it is some variable in my program that can be different depending on the inputs from the user), I have an array A_j. I would like to obtain the cartesian product of all the arrays A_j, so that I can then iterate through that cartesian product (taking one element from each A_1, A_2, ... A_n to get a tuple (a_1, a_2, ..., a_n) in A_1 x A_2 x ... x A_n). How would I accomplish this in Julia?

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Iterators.product`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/iterators/#Base.Iterators.product):

```
help?> Iterators.product
  product(iters...)

  Return an iterator over the product of several iterators. Each generated
  element is a tuple whose ith element comes from the ith argument iterator.
  The first iterator changes the fastest.

  Examples
  ≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡

  julia> collect(Iterators.product(1:2, 3:5))
  2×3 Matrix{Tuple{Int64, Int64}}:
   (1, 3)  (1, 4)  (1, 5)
   (2, 3)  (2, 4)  (2, 5)
```

Comment: Yes, but I forgot to mention (now edited it), the value of n is not fixed. So like in your example we have a fixed value of n = 2. How would one accomplish it though if n could vary? n is just some variable in my program

Comment: You can [splat](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/faq/#...-splits-one-argument-into-many-different-arguments-in-function-calls) the vectors into the product with `Iterators.product(As...)`.

Comment: It's still unclear to me how to do that. Could you clarify please how I would use the splat?

Comment: You would use it exactly like @graphtheory12345678 wrote: `Iterators.product(As...)`. If that doesn't combine with your code, @VincentYu, you'll have to supply a minimal working example so posters can find out how to show you. It's impossible to give you the exact code, when we don't know the names and types of your variables.